# Setup Ivy local repository in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, ivy

I am having issue setting up ivy local repository in Gradle(Android Studio).

I have setup a local server and put a test jar file in following paths:

http://192.168.0.101/gradle/maven_repo/com/example/repository/maven_example/1.0/maven_example-1.0.jar

http://192.168.0.101/gradle/ivy_repo/com/example/repository/ivy_example/2.0.2/ivy_example-2.0.2.jar

Following is my Gradle code:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        name 'My Custom Repository'
        url 'http://192.168.0.101/gradle/maven_repo/'
    }
    ivy {
        url 'http://192.168.0.101/gradle/ivy_repo/'
        layout 'pattern', {
            artifact '[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]'
            ivy '[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.example.repository:maven_example:1.0'
    compile 'com.example.repository:ivy_example:2.0.2'
}
```

The dependency from custom  maven-repository is getting resolved successfully but dependency from custom Ivy-repository is giving following error:

> Failed to resolve: com.example.repository:ivy_example:2.0.2

Can anyone point me in the right direction or suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the following pattern instead:

```
repositories {
    ..
    ..
    ivy {
        url 'http://192.168.0.101/gradle/ivy_repo/'
        layout 'pattern', {
            artifact '[orgPath]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]'
            ivy '[orgPath]/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml'
        }
    }
}
```

"orgPath" instead of "organisation". See the [doco](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html#patterns)

Comment: I have tried your solution but it is giving following error: `Error:(37, 0) Could not find com.example.repository:ivy_example:2.0.2.
Searched in the following locations:
    http://192.168.0.101/gradle/ivy_repo/[orgPath]/ivy_example/2.0.2/ivy-2.0.2.xml
    http://192.168.0.101/gradle/ivy_repo/[orgPath]/ivy_example/2.0.2/ivy_example-2.0.2.jar`

Comment: @RohitGupta What version of ivy are you using? The "orgPath" attribute requires ivy 2.3. The error message you've listed suggests you're using an older version